# PHP 5.3 - 5.4 shim

Tags: php, polyfills, shim

My server is running PHP 5.2. Is there a collection of shims so I can use a least some new ability of PHP 5.3 in PHP 5.2? like:

`<?php if ( !defined('__DIR__') ) define('__DIR__', dirname(__FILE__)); ?>`

Comment: Do you mean something like [this link in the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.php)?

Comment: @Bjoern If I understand, the OP is asking if there exists a file to include which adapts 5.2 to include 5.3 native functionality via PHP code like the above. And earlier revision of this question mentioned a _shiv_ like the HTML5 shiv.

Comment: @Michael Ah, I didn't see that, hence the link in my first comment.

Comment: you could just create them yourself. just check out the parts that interest you and add them to a php file

Comment: @Thanks for your comment. It's clear that I am looking for an off the shelf solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't recall all the features 5.3 and 5.4 brought to the table but the short answer is: no.

5.3: Feature you mentioned (`__DIR__` constant) is impossible to replicate unless you want to start every file with mentioned declaration (remember every file has different location).

5.3: Closures can be simulated using `create_function()` but context passing with `use()` or any new syntax won't be accessible.

5.4: Traits can be simulated using external configs and `__call()` handlers, but you'll need to write or inherit them in every class.

5.4: Short array syntax is, well, impossible.

The list goes on (binary notation, array item dereferencing, etc.) but answer is still - no.

As for one example where it worked, there is a "polyfill" for PHP 5.5's `array_column()` function, you can find it below. It's too long to include in answer, so please don't vote it as link-only.

http://benramsey.com/blog/2013/07/the-array-column-php-userland-library/
https://github.com/ramsey/array_column

Look also at the project which emulates all functions brought up in PHP 5.1 and up: https://github.com/Polycademy/upgradephp

Comment: [Please, don't invent your own implementation of array_column().](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php#112653)

Comment: That's not my implementation, I copied it from that GitHub link. Thanks for your reference, I'm editing my answer now.

Comment: Apparently the comment on php.net I linked above has been deleted. Here are the links about the "official" array_column() polyfill: [blog post](http://benramsey.com/blog/2013/07/the-array-column-php-userland-library/), [@GitHub](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column), [@Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/rhumsaa/array_column)